# Porting uint from c to c#

Tags: c#, c, porting

I am porting `C` program to `C#`

In c program i have this piece of code

```
uint32_t *st = (uint32_t*)((uint8_t*)rawptr+4);
uint64_t *d = (uint64_t*)((uint8_t*)rawptr+8);
uint8_t err = st[0] >> 24;
uint8_t type = (st[0] >> 24) & 0x3;
uint32_t nybble = st[0] & 0x0ffffff;
```

I tried to convert it in c#

```
uint[] st = (uint)((byte)rawptr + 4);
ulong d = (ulong)((byte)rawptr + 8);
byte err = st[0] >> 24;
byte type = (st[0] >> 24) & 0x3;
uint nybble = st[0] & 0x0ffffff;
```

But in this situation i meet the `CS00029` ERROR (`Cannot convert from uint to uint[]`)

I tried also to change it to

```
uint st = (uint)((byte)rawptr + 4);
ulong d = (ulong)((byte)rawptr + 8);
byte err = st[0] >> 24;
byte type = (st[0] >> 24) & 0x3;
uint nybble = st[0] & 0x0ffffff;`
```

But in this case  the error is `CS00021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'uint'`

Can you please help me to solve this problem ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: how do you define `rawptr` in the C# code?

Comment: What is `rawptr`?  Where does it point?

Comment: You can't use **any** pointers in C# outside an `unsafe` block ... if you have one, please show it .. see also [mcve]

Comment: Please provide a minimum and complete example

Comment: Hello, about rawptr 
    rawptr = (object)(BitConverter.ToString(data) + i * MAX_DATASET_SIZE);

Comment: The way arrays behave in C# is dramatically different from C.  Look like some kind of deserialization code, albeit that the snippet is not exactly good enough to tell.  BinaryReader ought to help, & and >> are not different.

Comment: surely it should be `uint[] st = (uint[])((byte)rawptr + 4);` the c code said `(uint*)` not `(uint)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a lot of refactoring to do.

You could use classes such as BinaryReader, or BitConverter.

Assuming rawptr can be converted or read in as a byte array:  (I'll also rename it to rawBytes)

```
  byte[] rawBytes = new byte[DATA_LENGTH];

  UInt32 bitmaskedWord = BitConverter.ToUInt32(rawBytes, 0);
  UInt32 st = BitConverter.ToUInt32(rawBytes, 4);
  UInt32 d = BitConverter.ToUInt32(rawBytes, 8);

  bool err = (bitmaskedWord & 0xFF) != 0;
  UInt32 type = bitmaskedWord & 0x3;
  UInt32 nybble = bitmaskedWord & 0x0ffffff;
```

A byte stream may be a better solution, especially if there is an undetermined amount of data in rawptr.  In this case, use BinaryReader.